# WM_SETFOCUS, where defined for C#?

Tags: c#, definition

I need to find out where WM_SETFOCUS is defined.
For instance, I know it isn't System.Windows.Forms.WM_SETFOCUS

I've looked online, and everything seems to just use the name with no mention of how to let your compiler know the name.

I DO know the integer value it represents, but I really want to reference an authoritative assembly, and not just litter my code with constants.

I am using the value in a class which implements IMessageFilter.

**ADDED DETAILS:**

Using IMessageFilter,
I am getting messages, and the messages have a Msg field (int) which identifies its type.  Where can I find C# definitions of those integer values?  (I don't need one named WM_SETFOCUS, I just need something with all the definitions of the values I am receiving.)
Since Microsoft supplies IMessageFilter, shouldn't they also supply the information needed to make it useful?

Comment: WM_SETFOCUS lives officially in the Windows SDK, in WinUser.h, not in the managed world. You can find some places where it's managed equivalent is defined (use Reflector for this) but it's not official (because also the .NET Framewor is supposedly "portable" wherever possible)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem to be defined in `System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.WM_SETFOCUS`  (Which, unfortunately is an internal class).  It's also defined in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.NativeMethods.WM_SETFOCUS`

Comment: Any idea what dll contains Microsoft.VisualStudio.NativeMethods ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about littering your code with native methods, I would do as the framework does and create an internal `NativeMethods` static class, and dump everything interop-related in it. At least you can keep it all in one place.

Comment: I just don't want the overhead of copying dozens of values, and referencing where they came from for future maintainability.

Comment: The value of WM_SETFOCUS and associated messages will never change - Microsoft cannot change them without breaking every Windows program every written.

Comment: @Mark: One of the few cases where a public const is appropriate.  There is no overhead and no maintenance.